# Property of object is undefined, even though console.log on object is showing the property value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, blob

I have an object dmDocumentLinks, when I print it to console it shows the object with property values.

`console.log(this.dmDocumentLinks);`
[image]
returns

```
createdAt: "2019-05-16T12:09:52"
createdBy: "admin"
documentBlob: "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"
documentBlobContentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
documentFileUrl: undefined
documentName: "word"
fileName: undefined
filePath: "files/AJUKzxL.vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
id: 577601
updatedAt: "2019-05-16T12:19:16"
updatedBy: "admin"
uri: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

but when I try to access a property of the object I get undefined

`console.log(this.dmDocumentLinks.documentBlobContentType);`

returns

`undefined`

The object has a Blob field, could that be the problem?

Full code

```
 setFileData(event, entity, field, isImage) {
        if (event['srcElement'].files && event['srcElement'].files[0] && event['srcElement'].files[0].size !== undefined && event['srcElement'].files[0].size < 1024000) {
            if (event['srcElement'].files[0].size === 0) {
                const translatedAlert = this.translateService.instant('error.emptyFile');
                this.toastrService.warning(translatedAlert);
            } else {
                const returnObject = {
                    event: event,
                    entity: entity,
                    field: field,
                    isImage: isImage,
                    dmDocumentLinks: this.dmDocumentLinks
                };
               console.log(this.dmDocumentLinks);
               console.log(this.dmDocumentLinks.documentBlobContentType);
                this.documentLinksChanged.emit(returnObject);
            }
        } else {
            if(event['srcElement'].files[0]){
                const translatedAlert = this.translateService.instant('error.fileSize');
                this.toastrService.warning(translatedAlert);
            }
        }
    }
```

`function setFileData(event, entity, field, isImage)` is called on change event in html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="hcmGatewayApp.dmDocumentLinks.documentBlob"
               for="field_documentBlob">Document Blob</label>
        <div>
            <div *ngIf="dmDocumentLinks.documentBlob" class="form-text text-danger clearfix">
                <a class="pull-left"
                   (click)="openFile(dmDocumentLinks.documentBlobContentType, dmDocumentLinks.documentBlob)"
                   jhiTranslate="entity.action.open">open</a><br>
                <span class="pull-left">{{dmDocumentLinks.documentBlobContentType}}, {{byteSize(dmDocumentLinks.documentBlob)}}</span>
                <button type="button"
                        (click)="resetBlob();"
                        class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs pull-right">
                    <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <input type="file" id="file_documentBlob"
                   (change)="setFileData($event, dmDocumentLinks, 'documentBlob', false)"
                   jhiTranslate="entity.action.addblob"/>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="documentBlob" id="field_documentBlob"
               [(ngModel)]="dmDocumentLinks.documentBlob" required/>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="documentBlobContentType"
               id="field_documentBlobContentType"
               [(ngModel)]="dmDocumentLinks.documentBlobContentType"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the `documentBlobContentType` property is set after the `console.log` statements. That is why `console.log(this.dmDocumentLinks.documentBlobContentType)` gives `undefined`.

As for `console.log(this.dmDocumentLinks)`, it displays the live object in the console. The property values are evaluated only when you click on the arrow to expand the property list. By that time, the `documentBlobContentType` property has been set, and you can see its value in the console.

To display the object as it is when the `console.log` statement is executed, convert it to a JSON string:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.dmDocumentLinks));
```

You can find more details on how to use `console.log` with objects in [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/mutating-objects-what-will-be-logged-in-the-console-ffb24e241e07) by Boris Sever.

Comment: yes, if I use ```setTimeout(() => {console.log(this.dmDocumentLinks.documentBlobContentType)}, 5000)``` it console.logs the value

Comment: Do you know how can I wait until the value is set?

Comment: If you define `documentBlobContentType` as a getter/setter property, you can call `console.log` in the setter.

Answer (score 0):

> try this,

```
var response = <any>(this.dmDocumentLinks);
console.log(response.documentBlobContentType);
```

Comment: still returns ```undefined```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like: 
`console.log(this.dmDocumentLinks && this.dmDocumentLinks['documentBlobContentType']);`