# Angular ngOnInit the object property is always undefined despite the the object has value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngoninit

I have an angular project and currently I am trying to set a reactive form values on ngOnInit method. I get the data with http call from a backend server. In the ngOnInit method I can monitor data on browser console; but the properties of the data object are always undefined despite the objects have this properties with proper values.

Here are the interested code blocks:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clientService.getClientBusinessYearDetails(this.clientBusinessYearId).subscribe(data  => {
         console.warn(data);
         console.warn(data.clientName);
         this.organizationDetailsFormValues.contactPerson = data?.clientName;
         this.clientProfileForm.controls.organizaionDetails.setValue(this.organizationDetailsFormValues);
    });
  }
```

You can see the details on the screen shot of browser console, the data object has a proper clientName property but it is showing up **null** when I try to using it in somewhere else:
[image]

The form that I want to set it's value is a reactive form which has several child form groups from inner components. I have simplified the ngOnInit method on purpose to read it easier.
when I set a control of form as hardcoded it is working and the value showing up on form but when I set the control's value as above it is not showing up because the property value is undefined.

Any Idea ? I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168632/property-of-object-is-undefined-even-though-console-log-on-object-is-showing-th) which quite similar but my goal is not showing the property's value on console.

Comment: your first log line shows that `data` is an *array* : check the value of `data[0].clientName`

Comment: @LeGEC Ohh my god yes , I just see it. It is working thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an array, just assign values of first element of this array.

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clientService.getClientBusinessYearDetails(this.clientBusinessYearId).subscribe(data  => {
         console.warn(data);
         console.warn(data[0].clientName);
         this.organizationDetailsFormValues.contactPerson = data[0]?.clientName;
         this.clientProfileForm.controls.organizaionDetails.setValue(this.organizationDetailsFormValues);
    });
  }
```